# проверка типа вводимых пользователем данных

Tags: java

делаю приложение для считывания двух чисел с консоли, последующего их сложения и вывода на экран на ваял такой код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Increment
{

     public static void main (String args[])
     {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        int f, t, r;


            do
            {
                f = 0;
                if (sc.hasNextInt())
                {
                    System.out.println("  Вот это я понимаю число!");
                    f = sc.nextInt();

                    break;
                }
                else if  (sc.hasNextDouble())
                {
                    System.out.println("Вы ввели непонятную дребедень Double");
                    continue;
                }
                 else if (sc.hasNext())
                {
                     System.out.println("Вы ввели непонятную дребедень");
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Что простите?");
                    continue;
                }

            }
            while (!sc.hasNextInt());

                do
                {
                    t = 0;
                    if (sc.hasNextInt())
                    {
                        System.out.println("  Вот это я понимаю число!");
                        t = sc.nextInt();
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (sc.hasNextDouble())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Вы ввели непонятную дребедень Double");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if  (sc.hasNext())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Вы ввели непонятную дребедень");
                        continue;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Что простите?");
                        continue;
                    }

                }
                while (!sc.hasNextInt());


        r = f + t;
        System.out.println(r);
    }

}
```

изначально планировал что если пользователь введет текст то будет вывод на экран и повторный ввод текста, но получается бесконечный вывод текста на экран, почему? в чем моя ошибка? подскажите как реализовать проверку вводимых пользователем данных, и последующее поведение программы в зависимости от типа введенных данных

Comment: А дебажить вы пробовали?

Comment: очевидно, что цикл замкнется, так как внутри него не вводятся данные. Условие выхода из цикла - число типа int, но если ввели не int, то будет бесконечная проверка первоначально введенного значения без возможности ввести новое.